# How does Darth Vader eliminate waste from his body?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-vader

I've always wondered what the deal was with Darth Vader's "crotch door". Does he use a catheter (due to all his injuries) or does he simply flip the door up and whip it out? I've never really seen the the back of his suit under his cape to see if there a corresponding "back door".

It doesn't look like he carries a catheter bag nor a colostomy bag in his suit or anything.

[image]

Is this addressed anywhere either in canon or legends sources?

Comment: Let nobody say that this site does not deal with the nitty and the gritty of sci-fi and fantasy.

Comment: [Even Robot Chicken couldn't figure it out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0ffCICQ-bU#t=1m29.4s).

Comment: He goes for an 1Z-2Z

Comment: He goes for a Count Dookie

Comment: You could randomly poke buttons on his chestplate to see which one causes the "crotch door" to pop up.

Comment: This question was predicted months ago, tongue in cheek.  The old gypsy woman was right.  The prophecy has been fulfilled.

Comment: @WadCheber - Does this mean I'm The Chosen One?

Comment: See also http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8674/1327 "How do fighter pilots manage food, drink & toilet?"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It gets *recycled*, erm, somehow. At least according to the [Star Wars: Blueprints - Ultimate Collection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756638690).

[image]

Given that the technology exists to utterly vaporise stuff in the Star Wars universe, there's really no reason to assume he needs to pee/poop at all.

Comment: This is truly the power of the Dark Side...

Comment: @GGMG the power of the Brown Side

Comment: "I smelt a disturbance in the Force"