# What is the shape on Darth Vader's crotch for?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-vader, armor

In this [related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/129693/54605), we learn that Vader somehow recycles his bodily waste within his suit. Which leads to another question:

**Then what is the shape on the crotch for?**

(Canon & EU/legends sources are acceptable)

[image: crotch door]

Comment: Are you sure it opens at all?

Comment: @armadillo - Not sure at all. If not, it would be curious that Sideous would simply have a hefty size engraving in that area just for aesthetics.

Comment: That looks decorative to me.  "Hey, look how big my robot junk is!"

Comment: It resembles the Elizabethan period codpiece. http://www.artofmanliness.com/2011/04/01/bringing-back-the-codpiece/

Comment: @Gandalf  +1 for teaching us what a codpiece is. Interesting article and might even be the right answer. If Batman and Robin had them, why not Vader?

Comment: @iMerchant Anyone who has read "Shogun" would be able to tell you what a codpiece is. There's an amusing bit when Mariko is trying to dress a drunkenly unconscious Blackthorne and she is quite puzzled by its function...

Comment: @Gandalf - You should write up your codpiece explanation as an answer. It seems very plausible as a suit/costume design by the Sideons/costume designers. Assuming nobody else comes up with a different, more specific answers, I'll approve it.

Comment: This question is awesome, and I liked the "door" version even more, even if it was less accurate.

Comment: [Retractable charging cord.](http://i.imgur.com/47g6mje.gif)

Comment: [Groinal Attachment](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BmE460EIAAAV2SJ.jpg)

Comment: Finally some half robot can actually go go gadget something for the ladies.

Comment: It's so he can still give people a flash of his manhood.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

David Prowse (the original character actor for Darth Vader) describes this as a "*protector*", the implication being that it protects his vulnerable parts, such as remain of them.

> **KH:** *Were you able to keep any of the original costume you were outfitted in?*
>
> **DP:** *When we were shooting, **the costumers couldn’t get any gloves or boots to fit me – nor the codpiece. So I had to personally supply
> my own gloves, boots, and protector.** Those three things I supplied for
> the Darth Vader costume, and never, ever saw them again.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Interview – David Prowse – by Kyle Harcott](http://www.thesnipenews.com/vancouver/events/david-prowse-vancouver-fan-expo/)</sup></sub>

Quotes from "[The Complete Vader](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Complete_Vader)" also have much the same info, again referring to it as a codpiece

> The pants (with suspenders) go on first, then the shirt and vest. **The
> codpiece is put on next,** then the chestplate with straps…. The cape
> should fall in pleats on either side of the belt buckle, with the
> light boxes arranged, one on each side of the buckle.”
>
> <sub><sup>[Inform The Troops, The Complete Vader Has Arrived](http://www.bleedingcool.com/2011/10/24/inform-the-troops-the-complete-vader-has-arrived/)</sup></sub>

As does the [Star Wars: Technical Journal of the Imperial Forces, Vol. 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9994695088)

[image]

You can see from earlier armours (in this case King Henry's from the 1500s) that the purpose of a [codpiece](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codpiece) is to accentuate the manhood as well as affording additional protection from frontal attacks against the groinal region.

[image]

Comment: Gird thine loins!

Comment: @Axelrod - That's not what [that means](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2014/10/02/how-to-gird-up-your-loins-an-illustrated-guide/), despite what Jilly Cooper and Jackie Collins want you to think it means :-)

Comment: Huh. Interesting! TMYK

Comment: Even though I chose the answer given by  @Valorum , both answers were very good and were virtually a toss up. If I were allowed to choose two correct answers, I would have in this case. I guess having a Star Wars related screen name put Valorum over the top subconsciously in my thinking. Great answers to both you and AncientSwordRage.

Comment: @Axelrod "**thy** loins". "Thine" means "yours".

Comment: @DavidRicherby It's also the version used for addressing multiple people, which is what I was doing.

Comment: @Axelrod [Citation needed]

Comment: @DavidRicherby [Citation](http://unenlightenedenglish.com/2009/07/thou-thee-thy-thine-ye-shakespearean-english/) : You now owe me one shrubbery.

Comment: @Axelrod No, that says that "thine" meaning "your" is used before vowels, and "ye" is the plural form of you (the one used for addressing multiple people).

Comment: @Axel Belated comment, but David is correct. As a possessive determiner, _thine_ (and _mine_) is to _thy_ (and _my_) as _an_ is to _a_; that is, it is only used before a vowel sound. _Thou/thee/thy/thine_ are all only singular, never used to address more than one person (except occasionally in some dialects, but that feature died out even before _ye/you/your/yours_ took over in the singular).

Answer (score 21):

The suit was designed first by Ralph McQuarrie, then refined by Oscar award winning costume designer John Mollo and production designer John Barry, as detailed [here](http://www.powerofcostume.si.edu/darthVader.html).

Here are some original drawings by Mollo:

[image: Original sketch by John Mollo with ovoid cotch design]

The design you're referring to here appear to sit just below the solar plexus, with no noticeable purpose, except perhaps to break up the large flat piece of costume.

You can see a minor resemblance to another of John Mollo's sketches of a snow trooper:

[image: Snow trooper without embossed lines]

This design does not feature any embossings, but the abdomen piece retains the similar aesthetic.

While I can't find a higher resolution picture, this seemingly earlier sketch also shows the shape, albeit lower and more prominently.

[image: Earlier sketch]

No lines appear to point it it however, and no purpose seems to be reveal either, beyond protection perhaps. This would have been before Vader's character had been finalized, and his history decided. The design was probably toned down, but remained for aesthetic reasons.

It's not uncommon for sci-fi armour to protect this region of the body, one example is from Judge Dredd:

[image: Judge Dredd in not much more than a leotard, codpiece and pauldrons.]

This is far more obvious, albeit still practical.

Comment: Nothing about Dredd's outfit is practical...

Comment: @Amadeus9 Judge Dredd isn't practical. He is THE LAW.

Comment: @amadeus9 I read referring to the protection it provides.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Have you seen his gun? That's all the protection he needs.

Comment: Is Dredd's really bigger than Vader's?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Darth Vader still needs to eat (does not live off of the power of the force) it would be impossible for him to receive nutrients intravenously (after a while your stomach gets bored and eats itself, not good). And if he does indeed eat, he would need some way to dispose of the bodily fluids easily and cleanly. He obviously cannot take his suit off as that would kill him, because his suit maintains his life. SO think of it as easy access to his waste bag...
Edit: apparently I was wrong, did not know that.... 
Thanks for the info.

Comment: His bodily waste is recycled. No bag to remove. See this related question/answer.  http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/129694/54605

Answer (score -1):

His entire suit is **pinstriped**. Why leave out  <strike>*my mom's most favorite piece*</strike> the most important part?

[image]

([source](https://www.google.com/search?q=pinstripe%20groin&biw=1024&bih=639&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8q8b7vZTNAhVBLyYKHY7sBtEQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=2Pl7tII-hkimOM%3A))