# How does Darth Vader poo

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

My four year son just asked this. I'm at a loss to answer.

Being still partially biological. But kind of stuck in the suit.

Has this ever been covered in old or Disney EU?

Comment: So you will accept Legends sources?

Comment: Related questions about eating: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103812/3804

Comment: Don't search for that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm so proud of myself at this moment.